# Adding Site Pages within a Site Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I have created a couple site pages containing lists and charts. All data being pulled and manipulated from a single list. I'm now trying to group the site pages within a single site page. My plan was to use add them all to a single page using `Page Viewer` Web parts then use some JQuery libs to create a tab view for each web part. However just including a site page within a site page is causing the page to redirect once the sub-site page loads.

Any tips or resolution on how to do this or will I need to recreate all the content into a single site page to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple web parts from the same list on a single page, each using a different view.  I would add all the views you need to one page and then use your JQuery to add each one to its own tab.  It will net you the exact same results and save you the headache of dealing with the ASPX files and redirection.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution. By keeping them seperate I could update each page independently

Comment: I just tested your scenario on SP 2013 and it didn't redirect.  I was able to display a page in the same Site Pages library on another page without issue.  I think you might wish to look at the content on your pages and see if something else is causing a redirect.  I don't believe this is an OOTB function of SharePoint even in 2010.